# An arraignment in Georgia

Tags: united-states, criminal-procedure, georgia

A hypothetical person is scheduled for an arraignment on a misdemeanor charge. His  attorney files a motion with the  court to postpone the arraignment. Assuming the court agrees with the  motion, will the court notify the defendant and if so how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The court will not notify the defendant. The court gives notice to the attorney who is responsible for informing the client.

Comment: Could the client call the court and would the court verify that the client does not need to show up?

Comment: @Paul59 The client could definitely do that.